# "Yum Update" on two CentOS Servers in Cluster but not on Third one, in cluster

Tags: linux, centos, yum

We have 3 Systems/servers in Cluster. (Wildfly server used inthat)

Colleague executed YUM UPDATE command on production on 2 servers and then done changes on installed Apache HTTP Server (HTTP Get Updated), Keycloak Server (Java package gets updated) and Wildfly Server accordingly.

But YUM UPDATE also updated multiple things:

```
NetworkManager-libnm.x86_64 1:1.18.8-2.el7_9                            NetworkManager-team.x86_64 1:1.18.8-2.el7_9
NetworkManager-tui.x86_64 1:1.18.8-2.el7_9                              OpenIPMI.x86_64 0:2.0.27-1.el7
OpenIPMI-libs.x86_64 0:2.0.27-1.el7                                     OpenIPMI-modalias.x86_64 0:2.0.27-1.el7
abrt.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos                                      abrt-addon-ccpp.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos
abrt-addon-kerneloops.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos                     abrt-addon-pstoreoops.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos
abrt-addon-python.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos                         abrt-addon-vmcore.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos
abrt-addon-xorg.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos                           abrt-cli.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos
abrt-console-notification.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos                 abrt-dbus.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos
abrt-libs.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos                                 abrt-python.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos
abrt-retrace-client.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos                       abrt-tui.x86_64 0:2.1.11-60.el7.centos
acl.x86_64 0:2.2.51-15.el7                                              alsa-lib.x86_64 0:1.1.8-1.el7
alsa-tools-firmware.x86_64 0:1.1.0-1.el7                                apr.x86_64 0:1.4.8-7.el7
at.x86_64 0:3.1.13-24.el7                                               attr.x86_64 0:2.4.46-13.el7
audit.x86_64 0:2.8.5-4.el7                                              audit-libs.x86_64 0:2.8.5-4.el7
audit-libs-python.x86_64 0:2.8.5-4.el7                                  augeas-libs.x86_64 0:1.4.0-10.el7
avahi-autoipd.x86_64 0:0.6.31-20.el7                                    avahi-libs.x86_64 0:0.6.31-20.el7
bash.x86_64 0:4.2.46-34.el7                                             bash-completion.noarch 1:2.1-8.el7
bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.7                                bind-libs-lite.x86_64 32:9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.7
bind-license.noarch 32:9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.7                             bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.7
binutils.x86_64 0:2.27-44.base.el7                                      biosdevname.x86_64 0:0.7.3-2.el7
blktrace.x86_64 0:1.0.5-9.el7                                           boost-system.x86_64 0:1.53.0-28.el7
boost-thread.x86_64 0:1.53.0-28.el7                                     btrfs-progs.x86_64 0:4.9.1-1.el7
ca-certificates.noarch 0:2021.2.50-72.el7_9                             centos-release.x86_64 0:7-9.2009.1.el7.centos
checkpolicy.x86_64 0:2.5-8.el7                                          chkconfig.x86_64 0:1.7.6-1.el7
copy-jdk-configs.noarch 0:3.3-10.el7_5                                  coreutils.x86_64 0:8.22-24.el7_9.2
cpio.x86_64 0:2.11-28.el7                                               cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.5-44.el7
crda.x86_64 0:3.18_2018.05.31-4.el7                                     cronie.x86_64 0:1.4.11-23.el7
cronie-anacron.x86_64 0:1.4.11-23.el7                                   cryptsetup.x86_64 0:2.0.3-6.el7
cryptsetup-libs.x86_64 0:2.0.3-6.el7                                    cups-libs.x86_64 1:1.6.3-51.el7
curl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-59.el7_9.1                                         cyrus-sasl-gssapi.x86_64 0:2.1.26-23.el7
cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64 0:2.1.26-23.el7                                   cyrus-sasl-plain.x86_64 0:2.1.26-23.el7
desktop-file-utils.x86_64 0:0.23-2.el7                                  device-mapper.x86_64 7:1.02.170-6.el7_9.5
device-mapper-event.x86_64 7:1.02.170-6.el7_9.5                         device-mapper-event-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.170-6.el7_9.5
device-mapper-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.170-6.el7_9.5                          device-mapper-multipath.x86_64 0:0.4.9-135.el7_9
device-mapper-multipath-libs.x86_64 0:0.4.9-135.el7_9                   device-mapper-persistent-data.x86_64 0:0.8.5-3.el7_9.2
dhclient.x86_64 12:4.2.5-83.el7.centos.1                                dhcp-common.x86_64 12:4.2.5-83.el7.centos.1
dhcp-libs.x86_64 12:4.2.5-83.el7.centos.1                               diffutils.x86_64 0:3.3-5.el7
dmidecode.x86_64 1:3.2-5.el7_9.1                                        dmraid.x86_64 0:1.0.0.rc16-28.el7
dmraid-events.x86_64 0:1.0.0.rc16-28.el7                                dnsmasq.x86_64 0:2.76-17.el7_9.3
dos2unix.x86_64 0:6.0.3-7.el7                                           dosfstools.x86_64 0:3.0.20-10.el7
dracut.x86_64 0:033-572.el7                                             dracut-config-rescue.x86_64 0:033-572.el7
dracut-network.x86_64 0:033-572.el7                                     dyninst.x86_64 0:9.3.1-3.el7
e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.42.9-19.el7                                        e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 0:1.42.9-19.el7
ebtables.x86_64 0:2.0.10-16.el7                                         elfutils.x86_64 0:0.176-5.el7
elfutils-libelf.x86_64 0:0.176-5.el7                                    elfutils-libs.x86_64 0:0.176-5.el7
emacs-filesystem.noarch 1:24.3-23.el7                                   ethtool.x86_64 2:4.8-10.el7
expat.x86_64 0:2.1.0-12.el7                                             file.x86_64 0:5.11-37.el7
file-libs.x86_64 0:5.11-37.el7                                          filesystem.x86_64 0:3.2-25.el7
findutils.x86_64 1:4.5.11-6.el7                                         fipscheck.x86_64 0:1.4.1-6.el7
fipscheck-lib.x86_64 0:1.4.1-6.el7                                      firewalld.noarch 0:0.6.3-13.el7_9
fontconfig.x86_64 0:2.13.0-4.3.el7                                      fprintd.x86_64 0:0.8.1-2.el7
fprintd-pam.x86_64 0:0.8.1-2.el7                                        freeipmi.x86_64 0:1.5.7-3.el7
freetype.x86_64 0:2.8-14.el7_9.1                                        ftp.x86_64 0:0.17-67.el7
gawk.x86_64 0:4.0.2-4.el7_3.1                                           gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-44.el7
gdb.x86_64 0:7.6.1-120.el7                                              gdk-pixbuf2.x86_64 0:2.36.12-3.el7
gettext.x86_64 0:0.19.8.1-3.el7                                         gettext-libs.x86_64 0:0.19.8.1-3.el7
git.x86_64 0:1.8.3.1-23.el7_8                                           gitlab-ci-multi-runner.x86_64 0:9.5.1-1
glib-networking.x86_64 0:2.56.1-1.el7                                   glib2.x86_64 0:2.56.1-9.el7_9
glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-324.el7_9                                           glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-324.el7_9
glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-324.el7_9                                     glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-324.el7_9
gmp.x86_64 1:6.0.0-15.el7                                               gnupg2.x86_64 0:2.0.22-5.el7_5
gnutls.x86_64 0:3.3.29-9.el7_6                                          gobject-introspection.x86_64 0:1.56.1-1.el7
gpm-libs.x86_64 0:1.20.7-6.el7                                          grep.x86_64 0:2.20-3.el7
grubby.x86_64 0:8.28-26.el7                                             gsettings-desktop-schemas.x86_64 0:3.28.0-3.el7
gssproxy.x86_64 0:0.7.0-30.el7_9                                        gzip.x86_64 0:1.5-10.el7
hostname.x86_64 0:3.13-3.el7_7.1                                        httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-97.el7.centos
httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.6-97.el7.centos                                hunspell.x86_64 0:1.3.2-16.el7
hunspell-en.noarch 0:0.20121024-6.el7                                   hunspell-en-GB.noarch 0:0.20121024-6.el7
hunspell-en-US.noarch 0:0.20121024-6.el7                                hwdata.x86_64 0:0.252-9.7.el7
info.x86_64 0:5.1-5.el7                                                 initscripts.x86_64 0:9.49.53-1.el7_9.1
ipmitool.x86_64 0:1.8.18-9.el7_7                                        iproute.x86_64 0:4.11.0-30.el7
iprutils.x86_64 0:2.4.17.1-3.el7_7                                      iptables.x86_64 0:1.4.21-35.el7
iputils.x86_64 0:20160308-10.el7                                        irqbalance.x86_64 3:1.0.7-12.el7
iw.x86_64 0:4.3-2.el7                                                   iwl100-firmware.noarch 0:39.31.5.1-80.el7_9
iwl1000-firmware.noarch 1:39.31.5.1-80.el7_9                            iwl105-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-80.el7_9
iwl135-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-80.el7_9                            iwl2000-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-80.el7_9
iwl2030-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-80.el7_9                           iwl3160-firmware.noarch 0:25.30.13.0-80.el7_9
iwl3945-firmware.noarch 0:15.32.2.9-80.el7_9                            iwl4965-firmware.noarch 0:228.61.2.24-80.el7_9
iwl5000-firmware.noarch 0:8.83.5.1_1-80.el7_9                           iwl5150-firmware.noarch 0:8.24.2.2-80.el7_9
iwl6000-firmware.noarch 0:9.221.4.1-80.el7_9                            iwl6000g2a-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-80.el7_9
iwl6000g2b-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-80.el7_9                        iwl6050-firmware.noarch 0:41.28.5.1-80.el7_9
jansson.x86_64 0:2.10-1.el7                                             jasper-libs.x86_64 0:1.900.1-33.el7
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.302.b08-0.el7_9                       java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.8.0.302.b08-0.el7_9
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.302.b08-0.el7_9              kbd.x86_64 0:1.15.5-15.el7
kbd-legacy.noarch 0:1.15.5-15.el7                                       kbd-misc.noarch 0:1.15.5-15.el7
kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7                            kernel-tools.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7                         kexec-tools.x86_64 0:2.0.15-51.el7_9.3
kmod.x86_64 0:20-28.el7                                                 kmod-libs.x86_64 0:20-28.el7
kpartx.x86_64 0:0.4.9-135.el7_9                                         kpatch.noarch 0:0.6.1-6.el7
ksh.x86_64 0:20120801-142.el7                                           langtable.noarch 0:0.0.31-4.el7
langtable-data.noarch 0:0.0.31-4.el7                                    langtable-python.noarch 0:0.0.31-4.el7
ledmon.x86_64 0:0.92-1.el7                                              libICE.x86_64 0:1.0.9-9.el7
libX11.x86_64 0:1.6.7-4.el7_9                                           libX11-common.noarch 0:1.6.7-4.el7_9
libXfont.x86_64 0:1.5.4-1.el7                                           libXi.x86_64 0:1.7.9-1.el7
libXrender.x86_64 0:0.9.10-1.el7                                        libXtst.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el7
libacl.x86_64 0:2.2.51-15.el7                                           libattr.x86_64 0:2.4.46-13.el7
libbasicobjects.x86_64 0:0.1.1-32.el7                                   libblkid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-65.el7_9.1
libcap.x86_64 0:2.22-11.el7                                             libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.41-21.el7
libcollection.x86_64 0:0.7.0-32.el7                                     libcom_err.x86_64 0:1.42.9-19.el7
libcroco.x86_64 0:0.6.12-6.el7_9                                        libcurl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-59.el7_9.1
libdb.x86_64 0:5.3.21-25.el7                                            libdb-utils.x86_64 0:5.3.21-25.el7
libdhash.x86_64 0:0.5.0-32.el7                                          libdrm.x86_64 0:2.4.97-2.el7
libffi.x86_64 0:3.0.13-19.el7                                           libfontenc.x86_64 0:1.1.3-3.el7
libfprint.x86_64 0:0.8.2-1.el7                                          libgcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-44.el7
libgcrypt.x86_64 0:1.5.3-14.el7                                         libgnome-keyring.x86_64 0:3.12.0-1.el7
libgomp.x86_64 0:4.8.5-44.el7                                           libgudev1.x86_64 0:219-78.el7_9.3
libicu.x86_64 0:50.2-4.el7_7                                            libipa_hbac.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10
libjpeg-turbo.x86_64 0:1.2.90-8.el7                                     libmount.x86_64 0:2.23.2-65.el7_9.1
libmspack.x86_64 0:0.5-0.8.alpha.el7                                    libndp.x86_64 0:1.2-9.el7
libnetfilter_conntrack.x86_64 0:1.0.6-1.el7_3                           libnfsidmap.x86_64 0:0.25-19.el7
libpath_utils.x86_64 0:0.2.1-32.el7                                     libpcap.x86_64 14:1.5.3-12.el7
libpciaccess.x86_64 0:0.14-1.el7                                        libpng.x86_64 2:1.5.13-8.el7
libproxy.x86_64 0:0.4.11-11.el7                                         libpwquality.x86_64 0:1.2.3-5.el7
libref_array.x86_64 0:0.1.5-32.el7                                      libreport.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos
libreport-centos.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos                          libreport-cli.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos
libreport-filesystem.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos                      libreport-plugin-mailx.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos
libreport-plugin-mantisbt.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos                 libreport-plugin-rhtsupport.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos
libreport-plugin-ureport.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos                  libreport-python.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos
libreport-web.x86_64 0:2.1.11-53.el7.centos                             libseccomp.x86_64 0:2.3.1-4.el7
libselinux.x86_64 0:2.5-15.el7                                          libselinux-python.x86_64 0:2.5-15.el7
libselinux-utils.x86_64 0:2.5-15.el7                                    libsemanage.x86_64 0:2.5-14.el7
libsemanage-python.x86_64 0:2.5-14.el7                                  libsepol.x86_64 0:2.5-10.el7
libsoup.x86_64 0:2.62.2-2.el7                                           libss.x86_64 0:1.42.9-19.el7
libssh2.x86_64 0:1.8.0-4.el7                                            libsss_autofs.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10
libsss_certmap.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10                              libsss_idmap.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10
libsss_nss_idmap.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10                            libsss_sudo.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10
libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.8.5-44.el7                                         libstoragemgmt.x86_64 0:1.8.1-2.el7_9
libstoragemgmt-python.noarch 0:1.8.1-2.el7_9                            libtasn1.x86_64 0:4.10-1.el7
libteam.x86_64 0:1.29-3.el7                                             libtiff.x86_64 0:4.0.3-35.el7
libtirpc.x86_64 0:0.2.4-0.16.el7                                        libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.4.2-22.el7_3
libusbx.x86_64 0:1.0.21-1.el7                                           libuser.x86_64 0:0.60-9.el7
libuuid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-65.el7_9.1                                      libxcb.x86_64 0:1.13-1.el7
libxml2.x86_64 0:2.9.1-6.el7.5                                          libxml2-python.x86_64 0:2.9.1-6.el7.5
libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.28-6.el7                                           linux-firmware.noarch 0:20200421-80.git78c0348.el7_9
lksctp-tools.x86_64 0:1.0.17-2.el7                                      lm_sensors-libs.x86_64 0:3.4.0-8.20160601gitf9185e5.el7
logrotate.x86_64 0:3.8.6-19.el7                                         lsof.x86_64 0:4.87-6.el7
lsscsi.x86_64 0:0.27-6.el7                                              lua.x86_64 0:5.1.4-15.el7
lvm2.x86_64 7:2.02.187-6.el7_9.5                                        lvm2-libs.x86_64 7:2.02.187-6.el7_9.5
mailx.x86_64 0:12.5-19.el7                                              make.x86_64 1:3.82-24.el7
man-db.x86_64 0:2.6.3-11.el7                                            man-pages-overrides.x86_64 0:7.9.0-1.el7
mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.68-1.el7                                      mdadm.x86_64 0:4.1-7.el7_9
microcode_ctl.x86_64 2:2.1-73.11.el7_9                                  mlocate.x86_64 0:0.26-8.el7
mod_auth_openidc.x86_64 0:1.8.8-9.el7_9                                 mod_ssl.x86_64 1:2.4.6-97.el7.centos
mozjs17.x86_64 0:17.0.0-20.el7                                          ncurses.x86_64 0:5.9-14.20130511.el7_4
ncurses-base.noarch 0:5.9-14.20130511.el7_4                             ncurses-libs.x86_64 0:5.9-14.20130511.el7_4
net-snmp-libs.x86_64 1:5.7.2-49.el7_9.1                                 net-tools.x86_64 0:2.0-0.25.20131004git.el7
nettle.x86_64 0:2.7.1-9.el7_9                                           nfs-utils.x86_64 1:1.3.0-0.68.el7.1
nmap.x86_64 2:6.40-19.el7                                               nmap-ncat.x86_64 2:6.40-19.el7
nscd.x86_64 0:2.17-324.el7_9                                            nspr.x86_64 0:4.25.0-2.el7_9
nss.x86_64 0:3.53.1-7.el7_9                                             nss-softokn.x86_64 0:3.53.1-6.el7_9
nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.53.1-6.el7_9                              nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.53.1-7.el7_9
nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.53.1-7.el7_9                                       nss-util.x86_64 0:3.53.1-1.el7_9
ntp.x86_64 0:4.2.6p5-29.el7.centos.2                                    ntpdate.x86_64 0:4.2.6p5-29.el7.centos.2
ntsysv.x86_64 0:1.7.6-1.el7                                             numactl-libs.x86_64 0:2.0.12-5.el7
open-vm-tools.x86_64 0:11.0.5-3.el7_9.3                                 openldap.x86_64 0:2.4.44-24.el7_9
openldap-clients.x86_64 0:2.4.44-24.el7_9                               openssh.x86_64 0:7.4p1-21.el7
openssh-clients.x86_64 0:7.4p1-21.el7                                   openssh-server.x86_64 0:7.4p1-21.el7
openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-21.el7_9                                        openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-21.el7_9
os-prober.x86_64 0:1.58-9.el7                                           p11-kit.x86_64 0:0.23.5-3.el7
p11-kit-trust.x86_64 0:0.23.5-3.el7                                     pam.x86_64 0:1.1.8-23.el7
pam_krb5.x86_64 0:2.4.8-6.el7                                           parted.x86_64 0:3.1-32.el7
passwd.x86_64 0:0.79-6.el7                                              pciutils.x86_64 0:3.5.1-3.el7
pciutils-libs.x86_64 0:3.5.1-3.el7                                      pcre.x86_64 0:8.32-17.el7
perl.x86_64 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9                                          perl-Getopt-Long.noarch 0:2.40-3.el7
perl-Git.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-23.el7_8                                      perl-HTTP-Daemon.noarch 0:6.01-8.el7
perl-IO-Socket-IP.noarch 0:0.21-5.el7                                   perl-IO-Socket-SSL.noarch 0:1.94-7.el7
perl-Net-SSLeay.x86_64 0:1.55-6.el7                                     perl-Pod-Escapes.noarch 1:1.04-299.el7_9
perl-Socket.x86_64 0:2.010-5.el7                                        perl-libs.x86_64 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9
perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9                                   pinentry.x86_64 0:0.8.1-17.el7
plymouth.x86_64 0:0.8.9-0.34.20140113.el7.centos                        plymouth-core-libs.x86_64 0:0.8.9-0.34.20140113.el7.centos
plymouth-scripts.x86_64 0:0.8.9-0.34.20140113.el7.centos                policycoreutils.x86_64 0:2.5-34.el7
policycoreutils-python.x86_64 0:2.5-34.el7                              polkit.x86_64 0:0.112-26.el7
postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-9.el7                                           ppp.x86_64 0:2.4.5-34.el7_7
procps-ng.x86_64 0:3.3.10-28.el7                                        psacct.x86_64 0:6.6.1-13.el7
psmisc.x86_64 0:22.20-17.el7                                            python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-90.el7
python-chardet.noarch 0:2.2.1-3.el7                                     python-dmidecode.x86_64 0:3.12.2-4.el7
python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-90.el7                                       python-perf.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7
python-pycurl.x86_64 0:7.19.0-19.el7                                    python-pyudev.noarch 0:0.15-9.el7
python-slip.noarch 0:0.4.0-4.el7                                        python-slip-dbus.noarch 0:0.4.0-4.el7
python-sssdconfig.noarch 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10                           python-urlgrabber.noarch 0:3.10-10.el7
quota.x86_64 1:4.01-19.el7                                              quota-nls.noarch 1:4.01-19.el7
readline.x86_64 0:6.2-11.el7                                            rfkill.x86_64 0:0.4-10.el7
rng-tools.x86_64 0:6.3.1-5.el7                                          rpcbind.x86_64 0:0.2.0-49.el7
rpm.x86_64 0:4.11.3-45.el7                                              rpm-build-libs.x86_64 0:4.11.3-45.el7
rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.11.3-45.el7                                         rpm-python.x86_64 0:4.11.3-45.el7
rsync.x86_64 0:3.1.2-10.el7                                             rsyslog.x86_64 0:8.24.0-57.el7_9.1
satyr.x86_64 0:0.13-15.el7                                              scl-utils.x86_64 0:20130529-19.el7
screen.x86_64 0:4.1.0-0.27.20120314git3c2946.el7_9                      sed.x86_64 0:4.2.2-7.el7
selinux-policy.noarch 0:3.13.1-268.el7_9.2                              selinux-policy-targeted.noarch 0:3.13.1-268.el7_9.2
setools-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.8-4.el7                                       setup.noarch 0:2.8.71-11.el7
sg3_utils-libs.x86_64 1:1.37-19.el7                                     shadow-utils.x86_64 2:4.6-5.el7
shared-mime-info.x86_64 0:1.8-5.el7                                     smartmontools.x86_64 1:7.0-2.el7
sos.noarch 0:3.9-5.el7.centos.7                                         sqlite.x86_64 0:3.7.17-8.el7_7.1
sssd.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10                                        sssd-ad.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10
sssd-client.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10                                 sssd-common.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10
sssd-common-pac.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10                             sssd-ipa.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10
sssd-krb5.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10                                   sssd-krb5-common.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10
sssd-ldap.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10                                   sssd-proxy.x86_64 0:1.16.5-10.el7_9.10
strace.x86_64 0:4.24-6.el7                                              sudo.x86_64 0:1.8.23-10.el7_9.1
sysstat.x86_64 0:10.1.5-19.el7                                          systemd.x86_64 0:219-78.el7_9.3
systemd-libs.x86_64 0:219-78.el7_9.3                                    systemd-python.x86_64 0:219-78.el7_9.3
systemd-sysv.x86_64 0:219-78.el7_9.3                                    systemtap-runtime.x86_64 0:4.0-13.el7
tar.x86_64 2:1.26-35.el7                                                tcpdump.x86_64 14:4.9.2-4.el7_7.1
tcsh.x86_64 0:6.18.01-17.el7_9.1                                        teamd.x86_64 0:1.29-3.el7
telnet.x86_64 1:0.17-66.el7                                             traceroute.x86_64 3:2.0.22-2.el7
trousers.x86_64 0:0.3.14-2.el7                                          tuned.noarch 0:2.11.0-11.el7_9
tzdata.noarch 0:2021a-1.el7                                             tzdata-java.noarch 0:2021a-1.el7
unzip.x86_64 0:6.0-22.el7_9                                             usb_modeswitch.x86_64 0:2.5.1-1.el7
usb_modeswitch-data.noarch 0:20170806-1.el7                             usermode.x86_64 0:1.111-6.el7
util-linux.x86_64 0:2.23.2-65.el7_9.1                                   vim-common.x86_64 2:7.4.629-8.el7_9
vim-enhanced.x86_64 2:7.4.629-8.el7_9                                   vim-filesystem.x86_64 2:7.4.629-8.el7_9
vim-minimal.x86_64 2:7.4.629-8.el7_9                                    virt-what.x86_64 0:1.18-4.el7_9.1
wget.x86_64 0:1.14-18.el7_6.1                                           wpa_supplicant.x86_64 1:2.6-12.el7_9.2
xdg-utils.noarch 0:1.1.0-0.17.20120809git.el7                           xfsdump.x86_64 0:3.1.7-1.el7
xfsprogs.x86_64 0:4.5.0-22.el7                                          xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64 1:7.5-21.el7
xz.x86_64 0:5.2.2-1.el7                                                 xz-libs.x86_64 0:5.2.2-1.el7
yum.noarch 0:3.4.3-168.el7.centos                                       yum-langpacks.noarch 0:0.4.2-7.el7
yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch 0:1.1.31-54.el7_8                       yum-plugin-protectbase.noarch 0:1.1.31-54.el7_8
yum-utils.noarch 0:1.1.31-54.el7_8                                      zip.x86_64 0:3.0-11.el7
zlib.x86_64 0:1.2.7-19.el7_9

Replaced:
    NetworkManager.x86_64 1:1.0.6-31.el7_2        docker-ce-selinux.noarch 0:17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos     grub2.x86_64 1:2.02-0.34.el7.centos
    grub2-tools.x86_64 1:2.02-0.34.el7.centos     iwl7265-firmware.noarch 0:22.0.7.0-43.el7              pygobject3-base.x86_64 0:3.14.0-3.el7
    rdma.noarch 0:7.2_4.1_rc6-2.el7
```

When i checked centos and found that 2 and 3 server has *CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)* but Server 1 (out of 3) has -> *CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)*

Applications are running fine on all three servers and communicating with each other. No System Restart taken place on any yet.

What are possible issues I could face in future in this setup on LINUX level? (I can see some NETWORK package updates etc. will it cause any network issue, timeouts etc?)

and what are suggestions to fix the same? Is there requirement to run YUM UPDATE on server 1 too?

Comment: No one here knows the details of your infrastructure including whether or not it it was kept at CentOS 7.2 for some reason or what versions the two that were updated had beforehand. You've stated that everything is working as it is but if you want to be absolutely sure, it's probably better to ask the community as you'd be communicating directly with people who are very experienced with it and perhaps even a developer. Here is a link to the forums: https://groups.google.com/g/wildfly

Comment: @NasirRiley: It is more about YUM Update on Linux. Not wildfly. More on network side or library which can hanper any xyz server including widlfly.

Comment: Unless you did something wild such as installing conflicting packages, packages that aren't compatible with the functionality of the system, or putting the system into dependency hell, updating the system with the package manager isn't going to break anything. That is done all the time as it's necessary to stay up to date with security patches, bug fixes, and new features.

Comment: It was plain YUM UPDATE. So it updates package x.2.20 to x.2.21. 
Such kind of changes are done. Even Java 8 updated to latest Java 8 package so need to update some configurations for that, same for HTTPD. But those are application level things which we can manage ; Just Server level packages like NETWORK packages, Kernel etc. even centos jumped to latest. So was in doubt.

Comment: Again, it's completely normal for releases of packages such as the kernel, Java, ruby, python, NetworkManager, openssh-server, httpd, etc to be updated. If you understand that, then what is the concern and what exactly do you need help with? Have you never updated the packages on a Linux system with a package manager before?